Is this stats question worded correctly?

It states "$25\%$ of your friends who like chocolate, also like sprinkles." which to me sounds like conditional probability $P(S|C)$, but the only answer that seems to come out is using it as the $P(S\ \text{and}\ C)$.
The way I arrived at an answer: $P(C|S) = P(C\ \text{and}\ S)/P(S)$
This implies it must be $P(C\ \text{and}\ S)$, but I can't understand why.
Thank you in advance for the help :(

There is no problem with the idea. "25% of chocolate lovers also like sugar granules" is indeed a conditional probability P (S | C), which can be used to calculate P (C and S) and then divided by P (S) to obtain P (C | S). It should be due to an issue with the question, and using this method would result in 0.4375 or approximately equal to 0.44.

Thank you! It was confusing since .44 isn't an answer option, but I've been struggling with this carnegie mellon course as almost every lesson has a misworded question.
I really appreciate the help!  Thank you for putting my mind at ease that I'm not misunderstanding the concepts.

That part of question means "Of all your friends who like chocolate, 25% like sprinkles."
Therefore, the correct probability to use is $P(S | C)$. You then multiply this with $P(C)$ to get $P(S \cap C)$, which you then divide by $P(S)$ to get your desired probability, which does not appear in the choices...
The question must have therefore been poorly worded.

The problem's real challenge is to reverse-engineer the official answer of $~63\% \approx 5/8.$
$5/8~$ of $~40\%~$ is $~25\%.$
So, you are to supposed to (somehow) conclude that $~25\%~$ of all of the people like both chocolate and sprinkles.
You have two other pieces of information:

$~70\%~$ of the people like chocolate.

"$~25\%~$ of your friends who like chocolate also like sprinkles."


There are two ways of interpreting the information in the second bullet point above:

The natural way is to presume that the percentage of your friends who like chocolate and sprinkles is $~25\%~$ of the $~70\%~$ who like chocolate. 
This natural interpretation leads to the conclusion that $~17.5\%~$ of your friends like both chocolate and sprinkles, which is inconsistent with the reverse-engineering.

The alternative interpretation is that the total percentage of your friends who like chocolate and sprinkles is $~25\%.~$  While this is consistent with the reverse-engineering, it has two problems:

For one thing, as others have indicated, if this interpretation is intended, the problem is ambiguously worded.

What is worse, if this interpretation is intended, the initial statistic of $~70\%~$ is unnecessary, and plays no part in computing the final answer.  This makes the reverse-engineering bizarre.




